# jsp with servlet

Tags: sql, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a jsp which retrieves data dynamically from db and shown in table format. Each row has a update button along with radio button. Whenever i click update on any row it proceed to next update page with only first row value.
Please help me how i could get the remaining rows for updating.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You will receive more responses if you edit your question so as to provide all relevant information.  If you need help doing so, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

1. define the corresponding id for the update button and the radio button of every row. I suggest you can define a hidden-text as it.
2. define a JavaScript function to resolve the logic:

   *a)* get the hidden-text value(id of the row record) about the selected update button or radio.

   *b)* create the target URL with id of the row record.

   *c)* submit id as URL parameter.
3. define a JavaScript function to refresh the corresponding row with the respond data. of course, you should define a java server interface to get the data of the row id.